# If then Statements format cells

Tags: excel, format, vba

I want to write a macro that will format cells if the column prior has a specific let.
For example let's say there is company ABC, DEF, GHI JKL, etc
Anywhere that Column B is for companies ABC and GHI then change the format in column C to "000000-00-0000"
Anywhere that Column B is for the other companies then change the format in column C to "000000-00-00"

```
Sub FixFormat()
    If Range("B") = ABC Then .NumberFormat B+1 ="000000-00-00"
    If Range("B") = GHI Then .NumberFormat B+1 ="000000-00-00"
    If Range("B") = DEF Then .NumberFormat B+1 ="000000-00-0000"
    If Range("B") = JKL Then .NumberFormat B+1 ="000000-00-0000"
End Sub
```

I know this doesn't work and I'm not the best at this type of thing so any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have the values from C1 cell you can try the below code as sheet module

```
Sub chgFmt()
    For Each rCell In Range("C1:C" & Range("C1").End(xlDown).Row)
        Select Case rCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
              Case "ABC", "DEF"
                    rCell.NumberFormat = "000000-00-00"
              Case Else
                    rCell.NumberFormat = "000000-00-0000"
        End Select
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I figured it out:
    
    Sub chgFmt()
        For Each rCell In Range("C1:C" & Range("C" &        Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        Select Case rCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
              Case "ABC", "DEF"
                    rCell.NumberFormat = "000000-00-00"
              Case Else
                    rCell.NumberFormat = "000000-00-0000"
        End Select
    Next
    End Sub'

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this?

```
Sub NumFormat()
Dim i as integer

For i = 1 to 100
Select Case Sheet1.Cells(1,i)
    Case "ABC" Or "GHI"
        Sheet1.Cells(1,i+1).EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "######-##-##"
    Case "DEF" Or "JKL"
        Sheet1.Cells(1,i+1).EntireColumn.NumberFormat - "######-##-####"
End Select
Next
End Sub
```

I'm doing this on a computer without Excel, so I couldn't debug, but let me know if that is the sort of thing you are looking for!  Also:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196401%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

A select case seems indeed to be a more practical way to solve your problem. An other way will be to make a rule directly in Excel, where you could say that if a Cell contains This, Then something happen.